# "Ошибка выполнения" при проверке кода для задачи: Найти среднее арифметическое положительных чисел

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Почему не проходят два теста?** Пишет: "Ошибка выполнения". Я уж не знаю что делать. Мне кажется это через тип данных. **Как исправить?**

```
n = int(input())
a = list(map(float, input().split()))
s = 0
count = 0
for i in range(n):
    if a[i]>0:
        s += a[i]
        count += 1
print("%.2f" % (s/count))
```

> **Задана последовательность вещественных чисел. Найти среднее
>   арифметическое положительных чисел.**
>
> *Входные данные*
>
> В первой строке задано число количество действительных чисел `n (0 < n`
>   `≤ 100)`. В следующей строке заданы n чисел, значения которых не
>   превосходят по модулю `100`.
>
> *Выходные данные*
>
> Вывести среднее арифметическое положительных чисел с `2` десятичными
>   знаками. В случае отсутствия положительных чисел вывести сообщение
>   **"Not Found"** (без кавычек).

[Задача](https://www.e-olymp.com/ru/problems/910)

Comment: Приведите полный текст ошибки. Подозреваю (на кофейной гуще), что размер списка `a` меньше `n`.

Comment: @andy.37, здесь не пишет, только вот: `
 # 2
Ошибка выполнения 20,17 ms 7 804 KiB`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш код не отлавливает случаи, когда было подано ноль положительных чисел. В цикле вы работаете только с положительными, отрицательные и нули вы игнорируете:

```
if a[i] > 0:
    # ваш код далее
```

Я бы исправил это добавлением **отсеивания отрицательных чисел** и добавлением **проверки на то, не равна ли длина массива нулю** после отсеивания.

То есть, как-то так:

```
n = int(input())
a = list(map(float, input().split()))

assert len(a) == n # проверяем, что длина массива равна количеству заданных чисел

a = [x for x in a if x >= 0] # обновляем массив, очищая его от отрицательных чисел

if len(a) == 0: # если после отбора не осталось значений
    print('Not Found') # печатаем Not Found

else: # иначе
    summ = 0 # заводим переменную для суммы
    for x in a: # проходимся по элементам массива
        summ += x # обновляем сумму
    print(round(summ / len(a), 2)) # выводим среднее с максимум двумя знаками после запятой
```

Comment: Что-то немножко не то выводит..Вхідні дані #1
3 5.2 -2 4, должно 4,6 вывести, а у вас 0,5

Comment: @Cactus Обновил

Comment: Да, пошло:) Спасибо!

Comment: @Cactus ещё раз обновил ответ. Ознакомьтесь с решением и комментариями. Примечание к изменению цикла: лучше проходиться по коллекции напрямую, а не по индексам. Но так как я неправильно понял задачу сразу, то начал использовать индексацию

Answer (score 0):

Ваш код просто не обрабатывает случай когда нет положительных чисел (когда следует `Not Found` вывести):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import statistics

_ = int(input())  # ignore 
positive = (f for f in map(float, input().split()) if f > 0)
try:
    print("{:.2f}".format(statistics.mean(positive)))
except statistics.StatisticsError:
    print("Not Found")
```